# faces-config strange configuration problem?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam

I have a seam project (you should not be blocked to answer just because it's seam, consider it beeing a jsf one) and all works great with jboss 5.1 until I add this to the faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config>    
<validator>
      <validator-id>passwordValidator</validator-id>
      <validator-class>com.mydomain.seam_icefaces_test.action.PasswordValidator</validator-class>
     </validator>

.....

</faces-config>
```

to configure a validator (I know I can use a seam validator but I just want to use a jsf one).

At this moment jboss continuously deploy and undeploy my app automatically - which is very strange of course...

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this happening when you deploy using a local server in Eclipse? I used to get this issue of constant deploying & undeploying - it was caused by an Eclipse versioning file in the deployment.

Every time you change a config file (like faces-config.xml) Eclipse creates a versioning file, to revert to if necessary. This screws up JBoss. Simply delete this file - it'll be called faces-config.xxxxx where xxxx is something other than xml.

Comment: so it's probably this file: .faces-config.xml.jsfdia

Comment: Do you know if this "feature" of eclipse can be disabled somewhere?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure where.